# Docker container copy files from local path into container

Tags: docker, keycloak

I need to copy my customized keycloak themes into keycloak container to use it like mention here:

https://medium.com/@auscunningham/change-login-theme-in-keycloak-docker-image-55b5fa5ceec4

After identifying my container id: `docker container ls` and making a list of files like this: `docker exec 7e3a420017a8 ls ./keycloak/themes`

It returns the list of themes correctly, but using this to copy my files from local to container:

`docker cp ./mycustomthem 7e3a420017a8:/keycloak/themes/`

or

`docker cp ./mycustomthem 7e3a420017a8:./keycloak/themes/`

I get the following error:

> Error: No such container:path: 7e3a420017a8:/keycloak

I cannot imagine where the error is, since I can list the files into the folder and container, could you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: the id is7e3a420017a8 and name keycloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works on my computer.

```
docker cp mycustomthem e67f76e8740b:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/raincatcher-theme
```

You have added the wrong path in command add full path `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/raincatcher-theme`.

Comment: Can I move .jar file of theme to above location and it should work ? Or Do I need to change something if there is jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

Update according to your new question update:

Try the following:

```
docker cp ./mycustomthem 7e3a420017a8:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/
```

The correct `path` in Keycloak is actually `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a weird way to approach this problem. Why not just have a Dockerfile that uses the Keycloak container as the base image and then copies the theme into the container at build time? Then just run the image you build? This will also be a more stable pattern in the long term if you ever decide to add any plugins or customizations and it provides an easy upgrade path to new versions by just changing the base image in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Or, even simpler, just mount the files when creating the container...

Comment: I have not access to the container